# Run android app on multiple physical devices Android Studio Java

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to test my app on multiple physical devices. On the first phone, the app works just fine, but after I installed (via USB) the app on the other device, the app opens but when tries to go to another activity it crashes.
Does anyone have any idea how to make the app work on both devices?

I have seen some solutions disabling the Instant Run, but on my version of Android Studio, I just can't find this option. SO, are there any other suggestions?

Comment: share your crash report please

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference" and it takes me to a line of code that on the first device doesn't have any problem.

Comment: you need to share the relevant code and the crash code in your question, please.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code that produces that error. Please respond with @AlexMamo